# Cannot edit nodes of layer imported from KML

Tags: qgis, kml

I'm new to QGIS. This group has helped me understand how to import KML files as vector layers, but once the data is imported, I cannot figure out how to edit the nodes of the imported polygons.  I can see them as red Xs when I toggle edit mode, but the node tool is greyed out/disabled.

How can I edit the nodes of these imported polygons?

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the layer you imported from KML, and choose "Save As...".  Choose "ESRI Shapefile" as the format, enter a save destination path, and keep the "Add saved file to map" box checked.

Once the save is complete, you should now be able to click on the layer that corresponds to your newly exported shapefile, and in edit mode, the node tool will be enabled and you can make changes to the nodes.

Comment: When you are finished editing, you can right click on the edited layer, and "Save As..."  back to Keyhole Markup Language (KML).